# SVG : <use> not cascade css with chrome or IE10

Tags: css, svg

I would like to use `<use>` on my document but I have problem with cascading classes.

I have the following svg:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <rect id="pattern" class="color-pattern" x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50"/>
    </defs>
    <g class="color-object">
        <use xlink:href="#pattern"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

with the following css :

```
.color-pattern {fill:red;}
.color-object .color-pattern {fill:blue;}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aab9y/2/)

With firefox the rectangle is blue (I seem it's right), with IE10 or Chrome, the rectangle is red.

Is it a issue ? How I can proceed for having a right result on three browsers ?

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: What if you reverse the order of the rules?

Comment: For user agents that support Styling with CSS, the conceptual deep cloning of the referenced element into a non-exposed DOM tree also copies any property values resulting from the CSS cascade ([CSS2], chapter 6) on the referenced element and its contents. CSS2 selectors can be applied to the original (i.e., referenced) elements because they are part of the formal document structure. CSS2 selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure.

Comment: It's Firefox that's wrong here. It's a known issue, there's a bugzilla bug tracking it.

Comment: Thank you, Anthony, Robert, It's necessary I could cascading style. I'll take another way, directly cloning the defs with JS.